# Matlab error "Integer operands are required for colon operator when used as index"

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm using a slider to increment values of `f`. It gives me the action I desire on my GUI -- but my command window shows this warning:

> Warning: Integer operands are required for colon operator when used as
>   index

In fact, if I output the value of `f` I see that it's not a round integer.

I've tried `fix`, `round`, `floor` etc to no avail.

Why am I still getting this warning?

```
f      = get(handles.slider_frames, 'Value');
f      = round(f);
window = 4;

while f > 0
    x = output(:, f:f + window - 1);  % <---- warning points to this line
    x = mean(x,2);

    %... code continues

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `round(f)` gives you value greater `0`.
If `round(f) == 0`, you'll end up with indexing starting from zero:

```
> f=0; f:f + 4 - 1
ans =
 0     1     2     3

> f=1; f:f + 4 - 1
ans =
 1     2     3     4
```

**Added:** To avoid this you should play with `Min`, `Max`, and `SliderStep` properties of your slider so `Value` will return you integer values (or at least values very close to integers witj minimal round-off errors).
For example, if you want

```
Slider.Min = 1;
Slider.Max = 79;
```

Then you should put

```
Slider.SliderStep = [1 10] / ( Slider.Max - Slider.Min )
```

In this case click on the slider button with arrow will increase slider value by 1, but when you click the slider trough, slider value will increase by 10.
See documentation on the `SliderStep` property of `uicocntrol` for more explanations.

Comment: thanks @anandr - what is the best way of ensuring `f` will be >0?

Comment: my `sliderstep` is set to `[0.01 0.1]`, and `Min Max` to `[1 300]`. However the `300` can decrease as a function of `window` var (eg, to 296). I sitll don't understand why `f=round(f)` doesn't work?

Comment: I do not understand it either. By the way, do you change `f` in your `while` loop or it runs infinitely?

Comment: `f` only runs between the `Min Max` values assigned to the slider. The `Min` is always 1, the `Max` is `300` but calculated based on `window` (ie `Max = 300 - window`). If user activates a pushbutton then `f=0` so you leave the loop.